# Xamarin Monodevelop - Error CS0103

Tags: macos, xamarin, monodevelop, gtk#

I just installed Xamarin Monodevelop on Mac OSX, I created a GTK# project where I have a very basic Window that I haven't even touched. This is the error it gives me on `Build();`

`Error CS0103: The name 'Build' does not exist in the current context`

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Build` method is created by the [Stetic](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/stetic/) UI builder, akin to the `InitializeComponents` of the Visual Studio UI builder.

There seems to be a bug in Xamarin Studio (I'm using 5.5.4.15) where the `Build` method is not generated unless you add a widget to the Window. Try adding a `VBox` or another container and then rebuilding.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  I've added several widgets but the Build method is still not generated.  Should it be generated and updated automatically on the fly, manually by some process I've not fathomed or is it supposed to be generated at build time?

Comment: it should be create by the Stetic UI builder. Are you using mono develop? What version?

Comment: I am indeed using MonoDevelop, details as below.  Incidentally, when I add action handlers to my widget the template methods are added appropriately to the MainWindow partial class...
---
MonoDevelop
Version 5.7
Installation UUID: 11d14ce4-f55c-4a71-b43b-53592db129a1
Runtime:
 Mono 3.12.1 (tarball Fri Mar  6 19:12:47 UTC 2015) (64-bit)
 GTK+ 2.24.23 (delorean-dark-3.10 theme)

Build Information
Build information unavailable

Operating System
Linux
Linux tony-HP 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It should definitely be there then. Can you reproduce this from an empty project? If so, please file a [bug in the stetic project](http://www.mono-project.com/community/bugs/).

Comment: Thanks, I will.  Just looked into the gtk-gui folder of a new project.  stetic file exists as does generated.cs and MainWindow.cs, but the MainWindow.cs consists only of opening and closing braces and not window building code.  Looks like some kind of misbehaviour.